# How to read operational attributes from ldap server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I have to read operational attributes from the LDAP server (createTimeStamp, entryUUID etc).

I have tried to implement own UserDetailContextMapper but without success.

At the moment my code looks like this

```
Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=users")
            .userDetailsContextMapper(userContextMapper())
            .contextSource(contextSource());
}

@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("ldap://ldap.company.pl:389");
    contextSource.setBase("dc=company,dc=com");
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return contextSource;
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsContextMapper userContextMapper() {
    return new CustomUserDetailContextMapper();
}
```

My UserDetailContextMapper implementation:

```
public class CustomUserDetailContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

@Override
public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<?
        extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    AutoUser user = new AutoUser();

    user.setCreateTimeStamp(ctx.getStringAttribute("createTimestamp"));
    user.setUUID(ctx.getStringAttribute("entryUUID"));
    user.setEmail(ctx.getStringAttribute("mail"));
    return user;
}

@Override
public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
    //default impl
}
```

}

I've tried `Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes(username, new String[] {"*", "+"});`

in `mapUserFromContext()` method, but I'm receiving `NamingException` if i pass `username`.

I was thinking about implementing ldapTemplate.lookup(), but I'm not really sure where to implement it, I've tried to do userRepo class with ldapTemplate, but I got `NameNotFoundException` with any DN I pass.

StackTrace for namingException from ctx.getAttributes()

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
at org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter.getAttributes(DirContextAdapter.java:865)
at pl.consileon.training.config.CustomUserDetailContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(CustomUserDetailContextMapper.java:21)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can retrieve object from LDAP using query like that:

```
public Object getAll(){
    return ldapTemplate.search(query()
    .where("entryUUID").is("<HasToPassUUIDFromLDAP"), new PersonAttributesMapper());
}
```

but I need to pass full attribute value, which is not the point since i want to retrieve this value, not the object with this value.

Comment: You are receiving what `NamingException`? Fulll error message and stack trace please. NB The first argument to `getAttributes()` is an RDN, not a username.

Comment: Edited post with stack trace. Actually, ctx.getAttributes throws exception if any Name/String with name is passed.

Comment: It is an RDN. Not a DN. Relative Distinguushed Name. Relative to the namespace of the context you call it on. You seem to be using a mixture of several APIs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ctx.getAttributes(username, new String[] {"*", "+"});
```

1. username - according to the documentation, this should be the DN
   That's how LDAP knows which record you're pulling data from
2. The second parameter, if you set it to `null`, it will retrieve all attributes

I believe your error is thrown because you're passing in a *username* instead of a *distinguished name*.

```
    /**
     * Retrieves selected attributes associated with a named object.
     * See {@link #getAttributes(Name, String[])} for details.
     *
     * @param name
     *          The name of the object from which to retrieve attributes
     * @param attrIds
     *          the identifiers of the attributes to retrieve.
     *          null indicates that all attributes should be retrieved;
     *          an empty array indicates that none should be retrieved.
     * @return  the requested attributes; never null
     *
     * @throws  NamingException if a naming exception is encountered
     */
    public Attributes getAttributes(String name, String[] attrIds)
            throws NamingException;
```